# DOS batch script in wine

Tags: wine

There is a windows program I'm trying to run.  When I run it, it says

```
wine: cannot find :"C:\\windows\\system32\\DO.exe"
```

I can't find a DO.exe program on my windows computer.  I suspect it's trying to run some kind of command script internally (Earlier it asked for `system32\find.exe`, which I was able to copy over).

So, is there a better way to run this so that wine will be able to translate and run the script correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to find.exe, do is not a windows program but is part of the cmd.exe shell (windows' commandline) and is used in for loops and maybe in some other places (don't know much of cmd.exe syntax).

Because the wine implementation of cmd.exe doesn't understand all of windows cmd.exe syntax, it try to look for an external executable for resolving a command that it should resolve itself, but there is no such thing as a do.exe executable.

You may try to look at what script is executed by your program (find .bat and .cmd text files) and edit for loops so that they run in wine.

Or if you feel brave you may look at [this patch](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21047) (see comment 2 attachment) and see if it helps (seems it will not apply to recent wine versions but should be easy enough to adapt).

Answer (score 1):

Associate .bat files with this command:

```
wine cmd.exe /c
```

or open from terminal:

```
wine cmd.exe /c <FILE>.bat
```

Comment: Hmm...  unfortunately, I don't still have this script to test this answer.  Hey - if anyone *does* use this answer and it works, let me know!